# Converting a dataframe to json and writing it to a File & appending a new Dataframe to that file

Tags: python, json

I need to write a Dataframe, converted to JSON format, to a file . This can be done quite easily with a one liner `df.to_json()` . Problem arises when I write it to a file because I need to append to the same file other dataframe as well. 
How it can be done efficiently

I am writing to the file using dataframe method `df.to_json(orient='records',path_or_buf='filepath')`

Now if I have another dataframe to be added to this file only then how it can be achieved (without loading it to memory)

Comment: Sorry but appending dataframes to json is nothing I heard about. Json is a string formated in a certain way. I'd suggest you wait with output until your dataframe is complete (use pd.concat or similar I guess)

Comment: Appending dataframe in Json format only. Not literally Dataframe. Actually I am fteching data from S3 and then converting it to dataframe , post cleaning it need to write it to disk. And with next iteration of fetch , I have to append data to the same file only. So later I can read whole data in a python Dataframe and work.

Answer (score 2):

Below code achieved what I wanted to do.

```
        filename='UserData'
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            dicts=userData.to_dict(orient='records')
            f = open(filename,"r+")
            f.seek(-1,2)
            f.write(json.dumps(dicts).replace('[',',',1))
            f.close()
        else:
            dicts = userData.to_dict(orient='records')
            f = open(filename,"w")
            f.write(json.dumps(dicts))
            f.close()
```

So, If `filename` exist then , file handle will be positioned to last and to maintain Json structure `[` be replaced by `,` .